# Question for api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo state call

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, javascript

I'm replacing `api.rpc.payment.queryInfo` with `api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo` in the crawler code of Polkastats block explorer but I want to ask about the second parameter `len`: is that the extrinsic lenght o what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct.

The encoded length of the extrinsic ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/transaction-payment/rpc/src/lib.rs#L103)).

Why is the len parameter required? The runtime doesn't know all the decoding context of the the encoded call ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L446-L448)). So you can't just pass the encoded call and calculate the length in the runtime, because it won't be able to decode it properly.

Some references that helped me unravel this:

- [what are the steps of encoding an extrinsic in substrate?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-are-the-steps-for-encoding-an-extrinsic-in-substrate)
- [additional info about signed extensions and weights](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/calculating-actual-weights-for-extrinsics)

Comment: Thanks, in the your referenced code the function get the lenght directly from the provided encoded extrinsic, which makes sense. Wondering why in polkadot-js you need to provide it as a different parameter.  As a side note, you can pass 0 as the `len` param to `api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo` and still get the same response.

Comment: Updated my answer which might help. When you pass 0 the fees that are calculated are incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the references!